# CSS not reflecting after modifications

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, css, cache

I'm new to Magento 2

I have an edited CSS file somewhere in app/design/frontend//web/css/, then I run the deploy static content command.
I can see the new CSS file is already in pub/static/ folder.
But when I access it through the browser, it is still the old one.
This is the old file: http://prntscr.com/mmhltc
And this is the new one when I add the "question mark" at the end of the URL: http://prntscr.com/mmhm4k

Could you please let me know what do I need to see my new CSS file? 
My Magento is 2.1.15

I have done the following so far:
 1. delete pub/static/ folder 
 2. run the deploy static content command again
 3. clear Magento 2 cache and storage cache
 4. flush CSS static file cache

Comment: is your site using cdn?

Comment: I have tried disabling CDN and flushing it.

Comment: I am sure you  issue with cdn which cdn you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Try running **`setup:upgrade`** command before redeploying static content.
The upgrade will remove all the static view files including cache files which allows redeploying static-content takes effect with the new static generated files.